# Redshift Copy with Newline Embedded in Quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Trying to copy data from S3 to Redshift with a newline with in quotes
Example CSV file:

```
Line 1 -->  ID,Description,flag
Line 2 -->  "1111","this is a test", "FALSE"
Line 3 -->  "2222","I hope someone
            could help", "TRUE"
Line 4 -->  "3333", "NA", "FALSE"
```

Sample Table:

```
TEST_TABLE:
ID VARCHAR(100)
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
FLAG VARCHAR(100)
```

If you notice in line 2 there is a linefeed and I get the error `Delimited value missing end quote` when using the COPY command.

This is the Copy command I use:

```sql
copy table_name
from sample.csv
  credentials aws_access_key_id= blah; aws_secret_access_key=blah
  DELIMITER ','
  removequotes
  trimblanks
  ESCAPE ACCEPTINVCHARS
  EMPTYASNULL
  IGNOREHEADER 1
  COMPUPDATE OFF;
commit;
```

I've also tried the CSV option, but get "Extra column(s) found ":

```sql
copy table_name
from sample.csv
  credentials aws_access_key_id= blah; aws_secret_access_key=blah
  CSV
  IGNOREHEADER 1
  COMPUPDATE OFF;
commit;
```

I would expect the description column in Line 2 to be loaded with the linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is delimited by quotes, use the [CSV option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv).

Note: `CSV` cannot be used with `FIXEDWIDTH`, `REMOVEQUOTES`, or `ESCAPE`.

Comment: I've tried using the CSV option and now get a "Extra column(s) found "

Comment: You should look at the row provided in the [STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL.html) table to see the data that caused the problem. It is possible that the `CSV` option can't handle the newlines either.

Comment: I did look at STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL and it states "extra column(s) found" using the CSV option on the next column after the column with the newline.  I am thinking it doesn't handle newlines either.  There has to be a way.  I'm sure there are many data files that has this particular issue as well.

Comment: FYI: [amazon web services - How to deal with Linebreaks in redshift load? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647130/how-to-deal-with-linebreaks-in-redshift-load?noredirect=1#comment101770876_57647130)

Comment: I found a fix not using the CSV option.  I added /n on the csv file for any fields which had a linefeed and added Escape.  I run a python script to programmatically add /n before loading to S3.  I then run the copy successfully to Redshift.