# How to deal with Linebreaks in redshift load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I have a csv which has line breaks in one of the column. I get the error Delimiter not found.

If I replace the text as continuous without line-breaks then it works. But how do I deal with line-breaks.

My COPY command:

```sql
COPY cat_crt_test_scores 
from 's3://rds-cat-crt-test-score-table/checkcsv.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::423639311527:role/RedshiftS3Access' 
explicit_ids 
delimiter '|' 
TIMEFORMAT 'auto' 
ESCAPE;
```

Delimiter not found after reading till `Dear Conduira,`

Comment: Have you tried specifying [the CSV Data Format Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv)?

Comment: Thanks John. I specified the csv format and had to remove escape. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) in the comments, using the CSV option is the right way to deal with this.

A more detailed answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024816/2130670).